# How to get the % of a given value (e.g., 0) separately per Subject and experimental Condition?

Tags: r

my raw data are like this:

[RAW DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnMb0.png)

and I need to get the mean % of values in Target.ACC which are equal to "0", separately for each Subject and conditions (i.e., Congruency and Figure), in order to get a table like that:

[% OF ERRORS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBq5Z.png)

in which there is only one row per subject and 4 columns for each combination of the two factors.

Anyone who could help me? Many thanks in advance,
M.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is `DF`. The approach is using `group_by`, `summarize` and `pivot_wider` of `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

DF %>%
  group_by(Subject, Congruency,Figure) %>%
  summarise(percent = 100*(n() - sum(Target.ACC))/n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("Congruency", "Figure"), values_from = "percent")

# A tibble: 2 x 5
#   Subject   c_A   c_B   i_A   i_B
#     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1       1    50  33.3     0 100  
# 2       2     0 100     100  33.3
```

You should install `tidyverse` to make it works

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
```

**My Data**

```
DF

#    Subject Congruency Figure Target.ACC
# 1        1          i      A          1
# 2        1          c      B          0
# 3        1          i      A          1
# 4        1          c      A          0
# 5        1          i      B          0
# 6        1          c      B          1
# 7        1          i      A          1
# 8        1          c      A          1
# 9        1          i      B          0
# 10       1          c      B          1
# 11       2          i      A          0
# 12       2          c      A          1
# 13       2          i      B          0
# 14       2          c      B          0
# 15       2          i      B          1
# 16       2          c      B          0
# 17       2          i      A          0
# 18       2          c      B          0
# 19       2          i      B          1
# 20       2          c      B          0
```

Comment: Hi nurandi, thanks a lot! Just another brief question: let say in another DF my variable Target.ACC contains 1, 0 but also 2, and I want to obtain the percentage of 2s...what change do I have to make on your code? Thanks!

Comment: Yo can change this line: `summarise(percent = 100*(n() - sum(Target.ACC))/n())` to `summarise(percent2 = 100*(sum(ifelse(Target.ACC = 2, 1, 0))/n()))`

Comment: Hi again Nurandi, I think there is only a small mistake in Target.ACC = 2, which should be Target.ACC == 2, right? After that, this code really works fine, and you helped me a lot!!! (in a previous comments I said I got another problem, but I forgot %>% after the summarise command...sorry)